# Understanding flow Spring Hibernate Example

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am building a small Application of Spring,Spring MVC & Hibernate by taking reference from

http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html

There are two methods defined:
 -> saveUser,listUser on UserDAOImpl class

Also, two methods (add,list) are on UserController.

My Question is: how the application knows which method would be invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the MultiActionController uses a [InternalPathMethodNameResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/InternalPathMethodNameResolver.html) by default. Tne controller is mapped to `/user/*.htm`, and the form posts to /user/add.htm. So the controller is invoked, and the method name resolver calls the add method because the path ends with `add.htm`.

If you plan to use Spring MVC for a new project, I would advise to read the spring reference documentation, because the MultiActionController is not the preferred way to have multiple actions in a single controller anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The method to call is selected by convention.

The form action in your example is `add.htm`. This maps to the `add()` method.